# I found an iPad on the street, how can I find its owner?

Tags: ipad

I have found an iPad on the street last night, it's an [iPad Air (Wi-Fi Only)](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=a1474) according to the model number (`A1474`).

- **How can I find its owner?**

The iPad is locked. There's no SIM card to help me find its owner. There's another question on this site [about an iPhone.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26710/how-can-i-find-the-owner-of-an-obstinate-iphone) But it's 6 yr old and may be outdated.

I thought about leaving it to the police, but according to what I read, they won't deal with it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  That question is old but it's still relevant.  You can't find the owner from the iPad if it's locked.  Take it to the police and tell them where you found it.

Comment: There's also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179052/ive-found-an-icloud-locked-iphone-how-can-i-return-it-to-the-owner?rq=1 though both QAs are rather out of date now. We could do with a new canonical QA for this issue

Answer (score 1):

Go to a place with a no password (open) WiFi. If your lucky the iPad is setup to connect automatically. Once it’s connected hold down the home button to activate Siri. If you are lucky and the iPad is set up to allow you to do this ask some of the following questions to help identify who the user is.

- Send a text to [random common name like Bob, John, Sam, Mike, Josh] I found this iPad and am not sure the owner if you could reply with owner and his/her contact info I colors return the iPad
- Send an email to [random common name] with same message as above
- What’s [common name]’s phone number? (Can be contacted separately)
- **Who am I? What’s my number? What’s my email? Where do I live?**

Hopefully one or more of these will work and allow you to get in contact with real people who know who owns the iPad

Comment: Does Siri work while the iPad is having Activation Lock?

Comment: @user7328702 No, but by locked I gathered the OP meant at that lock screen not restored and at the activation lock screen.